# How to signal the worker threads that there is some work to be finished?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I am building a small socket server where I want to create a thread pool and then work in boss-worker thread pattern. So, whenever a request is received by the main (boss) it is passed onto one of the worker threads from the pool.

In the following snippet,  I try to create 10 threads.

```
void* process_data(void* arg) {
    printf("invoked by the created thread");
    while(1) {
          // sleep until woken
          // get item from queue
          // do something
    }
}

int total_threads_to_create = 10;
int total_created = 0;
while(total_created < 10) {
   // create 10 threads
   pthread_t thread;
   int created = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, process_data, NULL);
   if(created == 0) total_created++;
}

while(1) {
   // server accepts the request in an infinite loop
   int socket_fd = accept(ss_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_sock,&client_sock_len);

   put_new_request_in_queue();
   // signal to one of the thread that work is available

}
```

As you could see above each new thread directly invokes `process_data` method. Now I want the thread inside `process_data` to sleep until woken by the main thread.

How do I:

- make the thread inside `process_data` to sleep until woken by main thread?
- how do I signal to the worker thread that there is a request to be served?

Comment: Condition variables?

Comment: @Shawn Could you please give an example? I read about them but not sure how to use them in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal solution is a condition variable and a queue.  The general pattern here is called the producer/consumer pattern.

You protect the queue with a mutex, and then use the condition variables to wake the workers

*Producer*:

```
workToDo = generateSomeWork()
acquire mutex
queue.push(workToDo)
cv.notify();
release mutex
```

*Consumer*:

```
loop:
    acquire mutex
    while queue empty
        wait on cv (releasing mutex while waiting)
    workToDo = queue.pop()
    release mutex
    do(workToDo)
```

Personally, I also like to add a boolean flag `done`, which is set to True when its time for all of the workers to clean up.  Thus, when you want to exit the program cleanly, you acquire the mutex, set done to true, then broadcast on the cv, which wakes up all of the works.  They see that `done` is set, and cleanly terminate.

Comment: In the producer, what is the need of acquiring a mutex? Could you please explain?

Comment: The producer also needs to release the mutex. @Amanda the mutex prevents the producer and consumer from accessing the queue at the same time.

Comment: @Amanda The queue is shared, so if two threads access it at the same time, you get a data race which results in undefined behavior (typically complete corruption and crashing of your program at some random time).  The mutex is used to ensure only one access it at a time.  Condition variables are designed to resolve a limitation with mutexes, which is that you can't know if the data changed when you're not holding the mutex, and the data cant change when you are holding it.  CVs provide a way to recieve that notification in a safe way without issues.

Answer (score 0):

### You have a Producer-Consumer, use a semaphore

You have written an example of the ["Producer-Consumer Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

The most appropriate control mechanism for managing a producer-consumer queue is to use a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

#### You also need to lock the shared queue

However, as you have multiple producers, you will also need a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) to ensure that no two producer threads attempt to write into the output queue at the same time (if you don't, you will corrupt your queue data structure).

The Wikipedia article for Producer-Consumer contains an outline solution for you, but doesn't use the exact same function-names as the pthreads library you're using.

#### Pthreads semaphore implementation

The pthreads library implements semaphores through the `sem_t` type and `sem_wait()` ("wait") and `sem_post()` ("signal") calls.

Comment: I'd be inclined to disagree that a semaphore beats out a condition variable (+ mutex) as "the most appropriate" control mechanism for producer / consumer problems.  The CV approach has some distinct advantages.

Comment: @John Bollinger Semaphores exist to address the shortcomings of simple mutexes when both ends of a pipe are able to sleep until action is needed.  Yes, you can get by with a mutex-guarded flag, but doing that means busy-waiting.

Comment: A condition variable is a synchronization primitive, not a "mutex-guarded flag", though such a flag is sometimes used in conjunction.  There is no busy-waiting with a condition variable -- that is pretty much the whole point of one.

Comment: My apologies, I missed the word "condition" in your first reply. Yes, it'll work, but it's not as good a model of what this program is actually doing. For this example, where the producer threads are filling a queue, semaphores are a better choice, as the counter aspect of the semaphore allow the producers to pre-fill the queue without waiting for the consumer to take an element out.

Comment: I agree that semaphores have that property.  I disagree that it swings the balance in their favor.  The counter aspect of a counting semaphore adds very little when the queue itself already contains all the needed information about how many threads could proceed at any given time.  CVs provide more meaningful advantages, such as not needing to access the CV at all under some circumstances, and cleaner shutdown.

Comment: My answer is the CV one, so clearly I'm biased, but I'll weigh in.  I find semaphores are a more exact match in this exact problem, without any alterations.  It's pretty much the problem that semaphores were designed for.  However, as the problem grows in complexity, the semaphore logic gets more complicated because all of the logic has to be done with the semaphore.  CVs win out in my mind because I get to do any arbitrary logic as long as somebody wakes me up and grabs the mutex.  For example, if I had a "high priortiy queue" that needed pumping also...

Comment: ... or if the queue needed dynamic memory allocations to manage an unbounded queue, the semaphore starts to get constricted, while the CV just keeps operating like any normal turing complete code.  The big advantage I see for semaphores is when multiple processes are involved *or* when you need to have one thread wait and another thread post (mutexes must always be released by the same thread they are locked by)

Comment: (My opinion is definitely affected by my first boss, who loved split semaphores.  This was back when Win32 didn't have condition variables, so split semaphores had a major cross-platform advantage.  I got to work with him as things got more complicated, and more and more of the split semaphores got refactored into CVs)